# image segmentation before image classification when the background is noisy (PlantCLEF2015 dataset)

Tags: image-processing, image-segmentation, transfer-learning, image-classification

I am trying to perform a classification task on the PlantCLEF2015 images. However, since some of the images have super noisy backgrounds, I was wondering maybe I should first segment my plant of interest out of the image and then run it through the classifier.

I am attaching two random images from the dataset to show how noisy the background could be.

[first image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVTao.jpg) /
[second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJcX4.jpg)